# Graphing Birthday Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been trying to graph the birthday function, but have been consistently unable to achieve the [commonly shown result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Birthdaymatch.svg) despite using the same equation. While I am aware that a simplified form exists, I would like to use the form of (P(366,x))/(366^x). [Attatched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YpWx.png) here is the result I receive from plugging the same equation into Desmos. Note how the function's y varies wildly with only small changes in x. How can I rectify this? Is this an error on Desmos' part? Thanks. I'd also be open to any suggestions regarding how to manipulate that function to produce a correct form.

Comment: Well, at least I believe you should use $365$ instead of $366$ in the equation (see: Calculating the Probability on the Wikipedia site.)

Comment: 366 for leap years. 365.25 wouldn't feel clean. Roughly the same either way. Any idea why it's showing up like that, though?

Comment: The vertical axis is logarithmic on the one plot and arithmetic on the other.

Comment: Yes, but what about the discontinuous jumps in my function not present in the other?

Answer (score 1):

Your plot is the correct one. $P(366,x)/366^x$ is a discrete function, which Desmos displays as a histogram, hence the jumps. The Wikipedia graph is a smooth extension of the discrete graph. They just do that to make it look prettier. Inherently, the function is discrete, since it only makes sense in the context of the birthday problem when $x$ is a positive integer. It should not be smooth.

If you want a smooth function, then you just have to use the Gamma function in place of any factorials. The Gamma function satisfies $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$ whenever $x$ is an integer, yet $\Gamma$ is defined for all real numbers, and is smooth. Therefore, $\frac{\Gamma(366+1)}{\Gamma(366-x+1)366^x}$ will be a smooth version of $P(366,x)/366^x$.